# Install idle-python2.7 under CentOS

Tags: python, centos, centos7, python-idle

I am looking to install an IDE for Python. I am working on a VM with a Python version of 2.7.5, and under CentOS7.

I am trying to install it on the command line under my terminal.
For now I only found commands with `"apt-get"` ..

When I try `yum install idle-python2.7`, I get this:

```
No python3-tools package available.
```

And when I try "yum install python-tools", I get this as an error:

```
[root@nexus-chat1 ~]# idle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/idle", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1507, in main
    root = Tk(className="Idle")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1745, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Or do you know of other IDEs for Python that I could easily install?

Comment: why there is the `# idle` command?

Comment: @aircraft To be able to launch the IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that `idle` is provided by package `python-tools` on CentOS 7.

And based on your description, it seems that the package is installed properly. You can verify that by running:

```
# rpm -q python-tools
python-tools-2.7.5-58.el7.x86_64
```

The error you see when you try to run it is caused by the fact that `idle` is a gui application, and you are likely connected via ssh without [X forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely) enabled.

Comment: I have the line : `python-tools-2.7.5-58.el7.x86_64`
How do I turn on x-forwarding?

Comment: See the [X forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely) link to answer on unix stackexchange site.